# Merge Sort vs Linear Sort: Proving Time Complexity with Python

Tags: python, sorting

So I'm tasked to prove how many times faster the worst case for merge sort is than the worse case for  quicksort in Python with an element of 500,000 values. So far, I've written the code for the merge sort, randomly selecting from numbers between 0 and a million  and here's what I have so far.

I was about to do the code for linear search, until I it dawned upon me that I don't know how to prove how many times faster the worse case for each algorithm - and how I would prove it.

What should I do?

Comment: "randomly selecting from numbers between 0 and a million" Please note that if you select a large number of elements at random, then the probability to hit the worst case for quicksort is extremely low. However, if quicksort always selects the first element as pivot, then a sorted list *is* the worst case. So I suggest sorting the list before you pass it to quicksort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timeit` module:

```py
import timeit

def merge_sort(input_list):
    ...

def linear_sort(input_list):
    ...

list_input = [50, 345, ...]

print(timeit.timeit(f"merge_sort({list_input})", setup="from __main__ import merge_sort", number=1000))

print(timeit.timeit(f"linear_sort({list_input})", setup="from __main__ import linear_sort", number=1000))
```

The `number=` determines how many times it should run the code. The `timeit` module accurately measures the amount of time taken to run a function. The setup code is needed to import the function for the `timeit` module to use and is not included in the time to run.

If you need to generate the list of 500k elements, something like this might work:

```py
import random

list_input = [random.randint(0, 1000000) for _ in range(500000)]
```

You could further contain the `timeit` code in a `while` or `for` loop and take the averages of several runs.

```py
for _ in range(10):
    merge_time += timeit.timeit(...)
    linear_time += timeit.timeit(...)

merge_avg = merge_time / 10
linear_avg = linear_time / 10

print(f"Merge Sort was {merge_avg/linear_avg}x faster than Linear Sort")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response~ I've been running it for some time now and I think it's still processing (1000 checks is a lot). Would it also be recommended to run it in under maybe 100 checks?

Comment: Yes, as long as you perform enough tries to get a good average. I would suggest running it once with `number=1` to get an estimate of how long it takes. Then, you can decide how many times to run it for.

Comment: and for it will be `merge_time += timeit.timeit(f"merge_sort({list_input})`

Comment: yes, the same code used in the first block: `timeit.timeit(f"merge_sort({list_input})", setup="from __main__ import merge_sort", number=1)`

Comment: Thank you so much! 

I'm currently having an error with naming as it states that 'name "mergetime" is not defined' even though i did 

`merge_time += timeit.timeit(f"merge_sort({inp_arr})", setup="from __main__ import merge_sort", number=1)`

Comment: You have defined `merge_time`, not `mergetime`. Make sure the underscores and capitilaziation is right. Also, if this answer helped you, I would appreciate it if you accepted the answer and gave it an upvote :)

Comment: If this answer helped you, could you consider accepting it :)